# Call Window Service from C# code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that hosted in windows services.
I'm trying to call the service from the code, when i'm in visual studio everything works fine, but if i'm closing visual studio and run the application from bin/debug/MyApp.exe i'm getting an exception )it can't find the service).
what should I do in order to call window service?
Thank you all...

Comment: Please post your code. We can't tell what might be wrong based on guesses alone.

Comment: you need to register Windows Service with *instalutil* command line util. You cannot start Windows Service as a normal .exe file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your programming error.

Simple, isn't it?

THat is about the only answer that is suitable for your question - you totally fail to give even a baseline Explanation.

I would look into

- Errors that happen in in the Service. Maybe the WCF Service is NOT hosted when starting outside visual Studio?
- Reading skills - targttted epecially at the exception you get, which seriously also includes a stack trace.
- Getting some nice Story telling skills. We all like you to tell nice stories, for example how the servie is configured, the relevant lines of code where you actually set it up.

Comment: i'm asking how should I do that and not how to solve a specific problem. if you have some code that doing the job, it can be wonderfull...

Comment: Nobody will be willing to do your job.
Nobody is able to do that either, because you are not willing to offer code or more details.

Comment: Well, and we are supposed to magically debug what YOU have on YOUR Computer, while you refuse to even provide the exact Errors you get? Get real - if you want other People to help you, you have to do more than appear clueless. A serious description of the error is baseline. Not "Help, help, i have no clue" but like someone who WANTS help.